# ERROR: A failure occurred in build(). while installing "checkinstall" help the newbie out

Tags: linux, arch-linux, compiling, checkinstall

I wanted to uninstall [conky](https://github.com/brndnmtthws/conky) that I built from source on my arch linux and [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439950/whats-the-opposite-of-make-install-i-e-how-do-you-uninstall-a-library-in-li) suggested installing [checkinstall](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/checkinstall/). But I am new to all this and `makepkg -sic` resulted in the following error -

```
makepkg -si
==> Making package: checkinstall 1.6.2-5 (Thursday 22 April 2021 12:28:02 AM)
==> Checking runtime dependencies...
==> Checking buildtime dependencies...
==> Retrieving sources...
  -> Found checkinstall-1.6.2.tar.gz
  -> Found 0001-Felipe-Sateler-Tag-only-regular-files-as-conffiles.patch
  -> Found 0002-Backtick-patch-from-Andrey-Schmachev-Copyright-year-.patch
  -> Found 0003-Fixed-bug-3-Removed-extra-okfail-and-fixed-spanish-t.patch
  -> Found 0004-Fixed-bug-1-Source-directory-package-name-with-space.patch
  -> Found 0005-Applied-patch-from-Ladislav-Hagara-for-compiling-ins.patch
  -> Found 0006-Added-Norwegian-translation-update-from-Andreas-Note.patch
  -> Found 0007-Added-summary-command-line-option.patch
  -> Found 0008-Fixed-glibc-minor-version-handling.patch
  -> Found 0009-Fixed-warning-about-uninitialized-variable-in-fopen-.patch
  -> Found 0010-Support-for-the-Makefile-PREFIX-variable.patch
  -> Found 0011-We-now-create-Slackware-packages-in-TMP_DIR.patch
  -> Found 0012-Fixed-bug-110.-create-localdecls-correctly-identifie.patch
  -> Found 0013-Fixed-bug-23.-We-remove-empty-fields-from-the-Debian.patch
  -> Found 0014-Fixed-typo-in-create-localdecls.patch
  -> Found 0015-Fixed-bug-30.-Newlines-are-converted-to-underscores-.patch
  -> Found 0016-Fixed-bug-38.-.spec-file-macro-processing.patch
  -> Found 0017-Fixed-bug-112-make-install-fails-on-Fedora-21.patch
  -> Found 0018-Fixed-bug-137-Missing-in-copy_dir_hierarchy.patch
  -> Found 0019-Fixed-bug-35-Directories-in-etc-are-incorrectly-incl.patch
  -> Found 0020-add-support-for-recommends-and-suggests-AKA-weak-dep.patch
  -> Found 0021-Load-checkinstallrc-from-etc.patch
  -> Found 0022-Drop-cases-for-glibc-2.4.patch
  -> Found 0023-fix-usr-sbin-merge-to-usr-bin-in-Arch.patch
  -> Found 0024-using-custom-cflag-and-ldflag.patch
  -> Found 0025-fix-installwatch-path-usr-local.patch
==> Validating source files with b2sums...
    checkinstall-1.6.2.tar.gz ... Passed
    0001-Felipe-Sateler-Tag-only-regular-files-as-conffiles.patch ... Passed
    0002-Backtick-patch-from-Andrey-Schmachev-Copyright-year-.patch ... Passed
    0003-Fixed-bug-3-Removed-extra-okfail-and-fixed-spanish-t.patch ... Passed
    0004-Fixed-bug-1-Source-directory-package-name-with-space.patch ... Passed
    0005-Applied-patch-from-Ladislav-Hagara-for-compiling-ins.patch ... Passed
    0006-Added-Norwegian-translation-update-from-Andreas-Note.patch ... Passed
    0007-Added-summary-command-line-option.patch ... Passed
    0008-Fixed-glibc-minor-version-handling.patch ... Passed
    0009-Fixed-warning-about-uninitialized-variable-in-fopen-.patch ... Passed
    0010-Support-for-the-Makefile-PREFIX-variable.patch ... Passed
    0011-We-now-create-Slackware-packages-in-TMP_DIR.patch ... Passed
    0012-Fixed-bug-110.-create-localdecls-correctly-identifie.patch ... Passed
    0013-Fixed-bug-23.-We-remove-empty-fields-from-the-Debian.patch ... Passed
    0014-Fixed-typo-in-create-localdecls.patch ... Passed
    0015-Fixed-bug-30.-Newlines-are-converted-to-underscores-.patch ... Passed
    0016-Fixed-bug-38.-.spec-file-macro-processing.patch ... Passed
    0017-Fixed-bug-112-make-install-fails-on-Fedora-21.patch ... Passed
    0018-Fixed-bug-137-Missing-in-copy_dir_hierarchy.patch ... Passed
    0019-Fixed-bug-35-Directories-in-etc-are-incorrectly-incl.patch ... Passed
    0020-add-support-for-recommends-and-suggests-AKA-weak-dep.patch ... Passed
    0021-Load-checkinstallrc-from-etc.patch ... Passed
    0022-Drop-cases-for-glibc-2.4.patch ... Passed
    0023-fix-usr-sbin-merge-to-usr-bin-in-Arch.patch ... Passed
    0024-using-custom-cflag-and-ldflag.patch ... Passed
    0025-fix-installwatch-path-usr-local.patch ... Passed
==> Extracting sources...
  -> Extracting checkinstall-1.6.2.tar.gz with bsdtar
==> Starting prepare()...
patching file INSTALL
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assuming -R.
patching file checkinstall
patching file description-pak
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assuming -R.
patching file installwatch/create-localdecls
The next patch would delete the file installwatch/description-pak,
which does not exist!  Assuming -R.
patching file installwatch/description-pak
patching file installwatch/installwatch.c
patching file checkinstall
patching file installwatch/installwatch
patching file checkinstall
patching file locale/checkinstall-es.po
patching file checkinstall
patching file installwatch/create-localdecls
patching file checkinstall-man.sgml
patching file installwatch-man.sgml
patching file locale/checkinstall-no.po
patching file checkinstall
patching file installwatch/create-localdecls
patching file installwatch/installwatch.c
patching file Makefile
patching file checkinstall.in (renamed from checkinstall)
patching file checkinstall.in
patching file installwatch/Makefile
patching file installwatch/create-localdecls
patching file installwatch/installwatch.c
patching file installwatch/libcfiletest.c
patching file installwatch/libctest.c
patching file checkinstall.in
patching file installwatch/create-localdecls
patching file checkinstall.in
patching file checkinstall.in
patching file Makefile
patching file checkinstall.in
patching file checkinstall.in
patching file checkinstall.in
patching file checkinstall.in
patching file installwatch/installwatch.c
patching file Makefile
patching file checkinstall.in
patching file checkinstallrc-dist
patching file installwatch/Makefile
patching file checkinstallrc-dist
==> Removing existing $pkgdir/ directory...
==> Starting build()...
for file in locale/checkinstall-*.po ; do \
        case ${file} in \
                locale/checkinstall-template.po)  ;; \
                *) \
                        out=`echo $file | sed -s 's/po/mo/'` ; \
                        msgfmt -o ${out} ${file} ; \
                        if [ $? != 0 ] ; then \
                                exit 1 ; \
                        fi ; \
                ;; \
        esac ; \
done
sed 's%MAKEFILE_PREFIX%/usr/local%g' checkinstall.in > checkinstall
make -C installwatch
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/privileged/applications/checkinstall/src/checkinstall-1.6.2/installwatch'
./create-localdecls
Checking truncate argument type... off_t
Checking readlinkat result type... ssize_t
Checking which libc we are using... libc.so.6
Checking libc version... 2.33
glibc >= 2 found
Checking glibc subversion... 33
gcc  -march=x86-64 -mtune=generic -O2 -pipe -fno-plt -fexceptions         -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS         -Wformat -Werror=format-security         -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection -Wl,-O1,--sort-common,--as-needed,-z,relro,-z,now -Wall -c -g -D_GNU_SOURCE -DPIC -fPIC -D_REENTRANT -DVERSION=\"0.7.0beta7\" installwatch.c
installwatch.c: In function ‘true_stat’:
installwatch.c:161:20: error: ‘_STAT_VER’ undeclared (first use in this function)
  161 |  return true_xstat(_STAT_VER,pathname,info);
      |                    ^~~~~~~~~
installwatch.c:161:20: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
installwatch.c: In function ‘true_mknod’:
installwatch.c:165:21: error: ‘_MKNOD_VER’ undeclared (first use in this function)
  165 |  return true_xmknod(_MKNOD_VER,pathname,mode,&dev);
      |                     ^~~~~~~~~~
installwatch.c: In function ‘true_lstat’:
installwatch.c:169:21: error: ‘_STAT_VER’ undeclared (first use in this function)
  169 |  return true_lxstat(_STAT_VER,pathname,info);
      |                     ^~~~~~~~~
installwatch.c: In function ‘true_fstatat’:
installwatch.c:173:23: error: ‘_STAT_VER’ undeclared (first use in this function)
  173 |  return true_fxstatat(_STAT_VER, dirfd, pathname, info, flags);
      |                       ^~~~~~~~~
installwatch.c: In function ‘true_fstatat64’:
installwatch.c:177:25: error: ‘_STAT_VER’ undeclared (first use in this function)
  177 |  return true_fxstatat64(_STAT_VER, dirfd, pathname, info, flags);
      |                         ^~~~~~~~~
installwatch.c: In function ‘true_mknodat’:
installwatch.c:181:23: error: ‘_MKNOD_VER’ undeclared (first use in this function)
  181 |  return true_xmknodat(_MKNOD_VER, dirfd, pathname, mode, &dev);
      |                       ^~~~~~~~~~
installwatch.c: In function ‘instw_init’:
installwatch.c:1209:3: warning: ignoring return value of ‘realpath’ declared with attribute ‘warn_unused_result’ [-Wunused-result]
 1209 |   realpath(proot,wrkpath);
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
installwatch.c:1328:3: warning: ignoring return value of ‘realpath’ declared with attribute ‘warn_unused_result’ [-Wunused-result]
 1328 |   realpath(__instw.root,wrkpath);
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
installwatch.c:1346:4: warning: ignoring return value of ‘realpath’ declared with attribute ‘warn_unused_result’ [-Wunused-result]
 1346 |    realpath(pexclude,wrkpath);
      |    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
installwatch.c: In function ‘true_stat’:
installwatch.c:162:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
  162 | }
      | ^
installwatch.c: In function ‘copy_path’:
installwatch.c:755:5: warning: ignoring return value of ‘write’ declared with attribute ‘warn_unused_result’ [-Wunused-result]
  755 |     write(translfd,buffer,bytes);
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
installwatch.c: In function ‘true_lstat’:
installwatch.c:170:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
  170 | }
      | ^
installwatch.c: In function ‘true_mknod’:
installwatch.c:166:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
  166 | }
      | ^
make[1]: *** [Makefile:22: installwatch.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/privileged/applications/checkinstall/src/checkinstall-1.6.2/installwatch'
make: *** [Makefile:12: all] Error 2
==> ERROR: A failure occurred in build().
    Aborting...
```

I am not sure what this means and searching online did not result in any useful hits  either.

Anybody well versed with this mind helping me out perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're not the only person to have seen this -- it seems that the package you're using has not been updated for glibc-2.33.  There's a patch at the end of [this thread](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1968712) which is supposed to fix that (though, be warned, it was only posted earlier today).

Comment: lol that's my post from arch. My threat here did not get any attention for 3 whole days so I thought I'd rewrite it here and also post it on arch forums. Do I just paste all that in the PACKAGE file in the checkinstall folder?